# My OOP design feels sloppy (C++)

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am writing a game in Cocos2D-x and I am struggling with feeling like my OO is sloppy. I can't shake the feeling and I can place m finger on why.

Game Scene class

- In This a Layer is created

Layer Class

- responsible for creating itself
- Also calls HUDS when needed
- contains std::vectors of objects on the layer

Object Class

- hold everything about itself
- has a sprite member variable that is on the layer

HUD1

- called when the user taps the layer and the touch even occurs in the Object
- is a Menu of things that you can do to the Object
- When you click a menu item it needs to change values in Object
- When you click a menu item it actually runs code in Object (object::doSomething())

What feels sloppy I think is that there is a lot of dependency on these classes together.

I feel like I should abstract this out and create a class that controls all of this happening instead of some code in Object, Layer, HUD, etc.

Can anyone talk to me about how this is laid out and if I am making an OO mistake?

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out graphics and games do not fit into OO designs very well despite being an example in many OO texts. Your instinct is right with respect to decupling the control from the data. A popular design pattern for games these days is to have components, entities, and systems instead of a rigid OO hierarchy.

The idea is that you have Entities or GameObjects that are just collections of components and perhaps some messaging infrastructure. Components store data about the Entity they are attached to, for example you might have a Transform component and a velocity component. Now one approach is to have a messaging system that components can hook into and use that to update their data. For example a Velocity component might hook into the Update message and in the Update handler it could get the transform of the object and move it. By using messages for all communication between components you can decouple them to a large degree.

Systems are a different way to handle updating component data. The idea with Systems is that you have a process that can say "I operate on entities with these components" and then it gets a list of all of the relevant entities when it runs. This decouples data from function even more and can make it easier to manage threading and dependencies

Essentially object oriented design is about capturing "what things are" in the real world, but with a game you don't really want that, all you care about is what things look like and you would like to be able to change the individual facets of something's behavior without pain.

Good resources for Entity-component systems:

http://piemaster.net/2011/07/entity-component-primer/
http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/

Comment: This is a great explanation. I will need to look up the concept of messaging systems to make sure I am understanding correctly. Let me read this a few more times

Comment: make sure to look into systems as well! often times they are better than messages because they give you more control over the order things happen in.

Answer (score 0):

Have a think about what you are trying to achieve before trying to dive in to code (even though the urge to do this is very strong!)

Try to decouple your classes by using Dependency Injection. This may involve adding a bunch of extra classes and complexity now, but trust me, it will make your life much easier later on when you will inevitably need to refactor certain parts of your game. Avoid using 'gum and duct tape' solutions as the technical debt you will incur by doing this will come back and bite you later!

Comment: this is good device and I have sat down with paper and drawn out these classes a few times. I still feel sloppy. Let me look up concepts for `Dependency Injection`